# When should I add a new tpl.php file, and when should I implement a theme function?

Tags: theming

Two part question, both highly related.

1. Can *all* templates be implemented both as a function in template.php, *and* as a separate tpl.php file?
2. In the cases where you can do both, are there advantages to either of the approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of theming something (`theme('function', $args);`)

### **Functions**

The call to `theme` will result in a theme function being called: `theme_foo` with the arguments which will return the HTML string to be outputted. These can be overwritten by creating `THEME_NAME_foo` function in `template.php`

### **Templates**

For template theme functions two things happens, `preprocess_foo` functions are called which will populate variables for the template. These can not be overwritten, but new ones can be added, as the alter an array which will contain all the variables used in the template by reference. The template file itself can be overwritten, by create a file withe the proper name. With use of suggestions, some can take precedence over others in certain cases. (`node-forum.tpl.php` used for forum type nodes vs `node.tpl.php` used for all nodes if no better match exists.)

### **Answer**

So in short, it depends on the definition of the theme function if you should use

- a template and/or preprocess function
- a theme function

But there is never a case where you can use a mix of these.

So

1. No, no template file can be implemented as a theme function.
2. No, you can never use both a theme function and a template, but you can use a preprocess function and a template.